# Is it safe to pass arguments by reference into a std::thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, standards, object-lifetime

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void f(const vector<string>& coll)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(1h);

    //
    // Is coll guaranteed to be valid before exiting this function?
    //
}

int main()
{
    {
        vector<string> coll(1024 * 1024 * 100);
        thread(f, coll).detach();
    }

    //
    // I know std::thread will copy arguments into itself by default, 
    // but I don't know whether these copied objects are still valid
    // after the std::thread object has been destroyed.
    //

    while (true);
}
```

**Is it safe to pass arguments by reference into a std::thread function?**

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's completely safe and okay.

Comment: You aren't passing anything by reference to the thread.

Comment: I apologize, you are correct; I misread the code.

Comment: I misread the documentation, he is using construct 3, I glazed over it initially

Comment: @T.C., I know `std::thread` will copy arguments into itself by default, but I don't know whether these copied objects are still valid after the `std::thread` object has been destroyed.

Comment: The `std::thread` object is no longer associated with the thread of execution because you `detach` from it. The `thread` itself will move the `vector` when calling `f`, that will bind to the `vector const&` parameter and its lifetime will end when `f` exits, so your code is safe.

Answer (score 6):

As @T.C.'s comment, you're not passing reference to thread, you just make a copy of the vector in the thread:

```
thread(f, coll).detach(); // It's NOT pass by reference, but makes a copy.
```

If you really want to pass by reference, you should write this:

```
thread(f, std::ref(coll)).detach(); // Use std::ref to pass by reference
```

Then the code will get segment fault if the thread tries to access the vector, since when the thread runs, it's very likely the vector is already destructed (because it went out of it's scope in the main program).

So to your question:

> Is it safe to pass arguments by reference into a `std::thread` function?

- It is safe if you're sure the object remains valid during the thread's running;
- It is NOT safe if the object is destructed, and you will get segment fault.

Comment: Clear answer for newcomers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- Is `coll` guaranteed to be valid before exiting this function?

  - **Updated:** Yes. When you pass `coll` to the constructor of a `std::thread` in `main` function, because `coll` is an object, it is `decay` copied. This `decay` copy essentially `move`s the vector (so it becomes rvalue), which will bind to the `coll` parameter in `f` during the execution of the thread. (Thanks for the comment by @Praetorian)
- Is it safe to pass arguments by reference into a `std::thread` function?

  - Your arguments are `decay` copied, so you actually never pass anything by reference to `std::thread`.
- Reference for `std::decay`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay/
- The accepted answer in this question [std::thread with movable, non-copyable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001751/stdthread-with-movable-non-copyable-argument) explained what happens to the arguments passed to `std::thread`

Comment: Can you elaborate what "`decay` copied" means? If it is not passed by reference, where/when is the copy made? Clearly a reference to the copy must be passed into `f` in OP's example. It might also be worth noting that lambdas still allow one to capture by reference without running into this decaying behavior.